# Numerically integrating the Friedmann equation at a turning point

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics

I've been solving the Friedmann Equation numerically, using this equation:

$$\frac{\dot{a}^2}{H_0^2} = \Omega_{0,M} a^{-1} + \Omega_{0,R} a^{-2} + \Omega_{0,k} + \Omega_{0,\Lambda} a^2.$$

I'm using the standard Euler method, setting

$$a(t+h) = a(t) + h \dot{a}(t).$$

The problem appears when I try to apply it to "Big Crunch" scenarios where $a$ has a maximum. If I just use my method, I overshoot the maximum and end up in a region where $\dot{a}^2$ is negative, which gives a complex $\dot{a}$. How can I continue the numerical integration through such a point?

Comment: Can you explain more? It sounds like you're saying "because an equation contains $x^2$, $x$ cannot be negative", which makes no sense.

Comment: @knzhou I've clarified it a bit more

Comment: @BetaDecay It's still somewhat unclear to me. Once you pass the maximum of $a$, it is $\dot{a}$ which becomes negative, not $\dot{a}^2$, surely? What exactly is failing in your simulation?

Comment: Okay, now I see your problem. I'm not really sure what the 'official' way of doing this would be. There's probably some complicated coordinate transformation so that the transformed coordinate $f(a)$ behaves more nicely, but I don't know if you want that level of complication.

Comment: However, you might be able to get away with what game designers do. When a ball bounces off a wall in a game, the designers don't actually do the bounce physics. They just detect when it's about to hit, then just manually reverse the velocity. Similarly, what you can do here is detect when $\dot{a}$ is getting really small, and then just flip its sign, so you avoid the turnaround region entirely.

Comment: The error is that you'll miss the time it takes to do the turnaround, but if you make your timesteps small enough that shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: @knzhou I see, that sounds good. I'll try that